# How to represent the Battery Temperature value in Wince using GetSystemPowerStatusEx2 API?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, windows-ce, battery, temperature

I just want to get confirmation on Battery Temperature data.

I am using GetSystemPowerStatusEx2 API to get battery temperature for windows ce device using c++..

I am using the variable say **"psse"** of type **"SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_EX2"**.

**On success**, the value returned for battery temperature is mentioned below:-

`psse.BatteryTemperature = 29 //which is of dword type.`

My doubt is what is the actual battery temperature representation?

Is it 2.9 degree celsius or 29 degree celsius & why?

Plz reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what is the _actual_ temperature?

Comment: I get 29 using the api, but while representation we need to multiply it with 0.1 to get actual value in degree celsius.

Comment: Ok, I mean, 29 is more believable value, than 2.9. Is your battery situated in the refrigerator?

Comment: @Lol4t0: It is present inside the windows mobile device. and i was trying to get the battery temperature for that device. And doing so i get 29 value which is 2.9 degree celsius.

Comment: But 2.9 Cecilius is _cold_. 37.22 degrees Fahrenheit. It probably not 2.9 Celsius in the room.

Comment: Battery Temperature value doesnot depend on room temperature value.

Comment: Battery Temperature value should at least _exceed_ room temperature, or I'm missing smth. If I take a thermometer and measure battery temperature, shouldn't it be _the_ battery temperature? But it can't be less the room temperature, because current heats it!

Comment: Even i too don't have that much idea on this. Somewhere while exploring in google i found out that the battery temperature is not dependent on room temperature. It basically depends on AC. When AC is plugged the battery temperature increases and at some point of time when Battery Temperature reaches the threshold limit the AC power doesnot charge the battery even though it is connected to the device.

Comment: I only want to say, that I suspect this API doesn't work at all, or works incorrectly, at least data looks unreliable at all.

Comment: I am not sure on that but this api is documented in msdn for collecting battery temperature info on windows ce device. Do you have any other api which can collect the battery temperature information for windows ce device?

Comment: This API probably depends on low-level device drivers. I don't know another API, but don't you find it strange, that [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/4ff6b3a1-8fad-4de4-8b44-2c95ea5ab058) temperature is 29 degrees also in the _original_ question? _Doesn't it always 29 degrees?_ Also note, that it should fluctuate in real life, you should get deviation of value from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926903.aspx)

> Battery temperature in degrees Celsius. This member can have a value in the range of –3,276.8 to 3,276.7; the increments are 0.1 degrees Celsius.

So a value of 29 means 2.9 degrees Celsius.

Comment: There: 'the increments are 0.1 degrees Celsius'

Comment: But in many places, i see that they multiply the value with 0.1 to get the actual battery temperature value in degree celsius.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/4ff6b3a1-8fad-4de4-8b44-2c95ea5ab058

Comment: @ctacke: Thanks for your response. Thanks to mauve & Lol4t0 as well :D

Comment: @ctacke: I have one more doubt, in msdn documentation they have not mentioned anywhere that a returned value need to be divide by 10... Does the sentence "the increments are 0.1 degree celsius" means to divide the value by 10. Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means

Answer (score 2):

did you zero out the BatteryStatusEx2 struct memory to zero before calling the function?

OTOH the OEMs can, but do not need to fill all values correctly. So if the function returns 29, which is 2.9°C, I assume the OEM does not fill the value correctly. Either it is ment as 29°C, which is alos not a real value over time, as the battery temperature should go up during usage of the device.

Posibly the OEM offers a new firmware or service release for the device which corrects the wrong reading.

The accuracy of the values depends on the implementation of the driver. Possibly the battery does not expose any temperature at all and the driver always fills the struct with the value 29.

Do not trust to much in OEMs implementing all features correctl all the time.

~josef